# Moq - It.IsAny<string>() always returning null

Tags: moq

What may cause `It.IsAny<string>()` to return null at every call?  Am I incorrect in assuming that it is designed to return a non-null string?

Here's the usage - where the Login method throws an ArgumentNullException for a null 2nd argument (connection string).  I was assuming that `It.IsAny<string>()` would provide a non-null string, which would bypass the ArgumentNullException.

```
var mockApiHelper = new Mock<ApiHelper>();
mockApiHelper.Setup(m => m.Connect(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                   It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                   It.IsAny<string>()));

var repositoryPlugin = new RepositoryPlugin(mockApiHelper.Object);
repositoryPlugin.Login(new CredentialsInfo(), It.IsAny<string>());

Assert.IsTrue(repositoryPlugin.LoggedIn, 
    "LoggedIn property should be true after the user logs in.");
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, [`It.IsAny<TValue>`](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/It.cs) just returns the result of calling [`Match<TValue>.Create`](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/Create.cs) - which in turn returns `default(TValue)`. That will be null for any reference type.

It's not clear whether you're really calling it on the right object though - shouldn't you be calling it on the *mock* rather than on the real code?

All the samples I've seen use `It.IsAny` in the context of a `mock.Setup` call. Could you give more information about how you're trying to use it?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've added the full test to the question.  I am using it both for my mock, as well as for a real object.  But it sounds like it's not intended for usage with actual objects?

Comment: @Jeremy: No, the idea is that you pass in real values (well, sample values) to your real code. `It.IsAny` is meant to be validating the values passed *from* your real code to your mocks.

Comment: Got it - so I had been thinking of it as a data generation technique...but it's not intended for that.  Thx!

Comment: If you want something to work as data generation look at pex. they play nice together imo.

Answer (score 11):

No, `It.IsAny` is used to specify in your Setup that ANY string passed will match.  You can do your setup so that if your method is called only with a particular string it will return.  Consider this:

```cs
myMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>()).Return(123);
myMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething("SpecialString").Return(456);
```

Whatever is using the mock will then get different values depending on the parameter the mock is passed when DoSomething is invoked.  You can do the same thing when verifying method calls:

```cs
myMock.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>())); // As long as DoSomething was called, this will be fine.
myMock.Verify(x => x.DoSomething("SpecialString"));  // DoSomething MUST have been called with "SpecialString"
```

Also, I see you edited your question.  Instead of:

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(repositoryPlugin.LoggedIn, 
    "LoggedIn property should be true after the user logs in.");
```

do this:

```cs
mockApiHelper.Verify( x => 
   x.Connect(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), 
       It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

Change times to whatever you expect. If you expect particular values, replace the relevant `It.IsAny<string>()` calls with those actual values.

Answer (score 3):

`It.IsAny` is used for matching its the code in your `Returns()` and `Callback()` that control what gets pushed into your tests.