# Why is this mock not working, yet it verifies?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I have the following mock (using [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/)) defined.

```
mockSqlConnection.Setup(x => x.Query<Address>(
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    null, 
    null, 
    true, 
    null, 
    null))
.Returns(new List<Address>
{
    new Address()
});
```

and the following verify

```
mockSqlConnection.Verify(x => x.Query<Address>(
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    null, 
    null, 
    true, 
    null, 
    null), Times.Once);
```

And both of those pass! Great!

Then i have this code which does the actual call..

```
var result = sqlConnection.Query<Address>(.....);
```

and that returns `NULL`.

I can't figure out why that is always returning null, when I've defined in a Setup, to return a list with one item in it.

#### UPDATE 1:

This works when I Test-Run my test.
But when i Test-DebugRun .. this is where all these errors occur!! :(

#### UPDATE 2:

If I force Moq to error (ie. use an inccorect Verify amount :: I expect once, so i'll say `Never` .. this is what it says when i HARDCODE the args .. or use the `It.IsAny<T>` ones..

```
Moq.MockException
Expected invocation on the mock should never have been performed, but was 1 times: x => x.Query<Address>(It.IsAny<String>(), null, null, True, null, null)

Configured setups:
x => x.Query<Address>(It.IsAny<String>(), null, null, True, null, null), Times.Once

Performed invocations:
IDbExecutor.Open()
IDbExecutor.Query(" -- code snipped --", null, null, True, null, null)
IDbExecutor.Close()
IDisposable.Dispose()

Moq.MockException
Expected invocation on the mock should never have been performed, but was 1 times: x => x.Query<Address>(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Object>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction>(), It.IsAny<Boolean>(), It.IsAny<Nullable`1>(), It.IsAny<Nullable`1>())

Configured setups:
x => x.Query<Address>(It.IsAny<String>(), null, null, True, null, null), Times.Never
x => x.Query<Address>(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Object>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction>(), It.IsAny<Boolean>(), It.IsAny<Nullable`1>(), It.IsAny<Nullable`1>()), Times.Once

Performed invocations:
IDbExecutor.Open()
IDbExecutor.Query(" -- sql query snipped --", null, null, True, null, null)
IDbExecutor.Close()
IDisposable.Dispose()
```

I don't get it :(

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing to the method?

Comment: it's irrelivant. notice how the mock says `It.IsAny<string>` etc..

Comment: What is the code you are using to actually call the `Query` method with the parameters?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098624/moq-it-isanystring-always-returning-null) So question

Comment: Thanks @Junaith but nope :( that SO q doesn't help because I'm not passing the `It.IsAny<T>` to some real code, but to the mock (which is an interface).

Comment: If I read your question correct you're setting up a mock object [mockSqlConnection] and then calling the actual object [sqlConnection] instead of the mock. I assume that is a typo...

Comment: Yeah - u misread. `sqlConnection` is the `mock.Object.`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because some of the parameters are hard coded. If you would like the `new Address()` to be returned regardless of the parameters, try this:

Parameters with `It.IsAny<T>()` allow for any value. If the parameter is a specific value, that specific value will be required for the `Setup` to act as you have defined.

```
mockSqlConnection.Setup(x => x.Query<Address>(
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<bool>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>()))
.Returns(new List<Address>
{
    new Address()
});
```

Your `Verify` will also need to use `It.IsAny<T>()` in order to pass correctly:

```
mockSqlConnection.Verify(x => x.Query<Address>(
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<bool>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>(),
    It.IsAny<TheType>(), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Nope - didn't work :( I ogorinally tried that also :( and then went to hardcoding.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Try updating your `Verify` also as in the above code

Comment: @rhughes using his sample i was able to create a passing test without issue so the problem *seems* to lie elsewhere...