# Return a single object from list

Tags: c#, moq

When setting up my repository I am trying to return a single Account object. It should return this object from a List where the username is equal to the parameter.

However I get the exception

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'IncrediStaff.DataAccess.Models.Account'.

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var repository = new Mock<IAccountRepository>();
        var accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account { AccountId = 1, Username = "John", Hash = "9f3Iv0NW9Jr3l+EmOS/zWCPe96k=", Salt = "y7qwIY0ep8aHiiSwl57dt4ueuCo=" }, // Password is, "TestPassword"
            new Account { AccountId = 2, Username = "Ryan", Hash = "63mnR/gbFIIU6vGEFqoY5H1QCCI=", Salt = "xi/lkLFqPPTR5Q9rX3m/PJ4FH0rECyalYdyRJ6pCpfE=" }, // Password is, "NewPassword"
            new Account { AccountId = 3, Username = "Sarah", Hash = null, Salt = null, FirstLogin = 1 }
        };

        repository.Setup(x => x.GetAccount(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns<Account>(r => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == It.IsAny<string>()));

        _service = new AccountService(repository.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Accounts")]
    public void UserPasswordIsCorrect()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_service.Login("John", "TestPassword"));
    }
```

If I return a single Account object the test passes.

```
        repository.Setup(x => x.GetAccount(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(new Account
            {
                AccountId = 1,
                Username = "John",
                Hash = "9f3Iv0NW9Jr3l+EmOS/zWCPe96k=",
                Salt = "y7qwIY0ep8aHiiSwl57dt4ueuCo="
            });
```

I'm not sure why it can't return a single object from the list. Furthermore I have another setup which uses the same list and the test passes. I'm not sure why this works and the other doesn't.

```
        repository.Setup(r => r.SelectIfUsernameExists(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns<string>(username => accounts.Exists(r => r.Username == username));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between passing It.IsAny<int>() and the value of It.IsAny<int>() to a method setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany)

Comment: Possibly, however even when I replace It.IsAny with "John" i'll still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check sources for this case to see your issue:
https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/b2cf2d303ea6644fda2eaf10bad43c88c05b395f/Source/Language/IReturns.cs
https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/b2cf2d303ea6644fda2eaf10bad43c88c05b395f/Source/MethodCallReturn.cs

Specifically, this one:

```
IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult> valueFunction);
```

Documentation says, that T is :

> The type of the argument of the invoked method

So the type of T in generic argument of Returns is really type of first parameter, that was passed into the function you are mocking in previous setup method.

Your setup does `x.GetAccount(It.IsAny<string>())` - it mocks method that has signature `Account GetAccount(string name)`, so method called takes one argument of type `string`.
So when you do `Returns`, your IDE already knows type of returned parameter - it's `TResult` as in documentation. If you don't specify generic arguments, it will always return the object you defined inside `.Returns()`. However, if you want to parametrize it based on your `.Setup()`, you need to explicitely tell what parameters in what order were passed inside the function you are mocking.
In your case there's only 1 parameter of type `string` that you pass - it's userName. So to do parameter binding, you have to pass its type - `string` - as a generic argument.

This is also made so that you could provide multiple parameters to your `.Returns` method, for example:
`.Returns<string, int, DateTime>((string str, int i, DateTime date) => ...);`

Comment: Ok, I'm beginning to understand now. I changed the Return method to .Returns<string> It works perfectly! I thought that T was the return type. I guess I should of read the source before hand.

Answer (score 0):

`It.IsAny<string>()` in the `Returns` clause will always returns null. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6098717/1077279). So your

```
accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == It.IsAny<string>())
```

is really

```
accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == null)
```

which will return null.

Instead you need something like

```
accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == "John")
```